Cycle in dependencies between targets ‘XYZ' and ‘XYZ_appTests' in Xcode for React Native project on macOS
Question:
I am setting up a React Native project on my MacBook Pro and have installed the necessary tools: Node.js, Xcode, Ruby, and CocoaPods. I've also configured .xcode.env properly. Despite following various troubleshooting steps, including reinstalling pods, I am encountering a dependency cycle issue in Xcode. This issue appears to be between the project target XYZ and its test target XYZ_appTests.
Here is the specific error message I'm receiving in Xcode build:
Showing All Messages
Cycle in dependencies between targets 'XYZ' and 'XYZ_appTests'; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: XYZ → XYZ_appTests → XYZ
Cycle details:
→ Target 'XYZ' has an explicit dependency on Target 'XYZ_appTests'
→ Target 'XYZ_appTests' has an explicit dependency on Target 'XYZ'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/ABC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ_app-fxthweyuptefnvbhpnarzdbbdzjd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ_app.app/Frameworks/XCTAutomationSupport.framework ->

command: P0:target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:Copy /Users/ABC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ_app-fxthweyuptefnvbhpnarzdbbdzjd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ_app.app/Frameworks/XCTAutomationSupport.framework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCTAutomationSupport.framework ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: <target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--ModuleVerifierTaskProducer> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--ModuleVerifierTaskProducer ->

node: <target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--ModuleMapTaskProducer> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--ModuleMapTaskProducer ->

node: <target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--HeadermapTaskProducer> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-XYZ-6f744c8ebba6034abf56e0311272f9237ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--HeadermapTaskProducer ->

node: /Users/ABC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ_app-fxthweyuptefnvbhpnarzdbbdzjd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XYZ_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.build/all-product-headers.yaml ->


I understand that this kind of dependency cycle can cause unreliable build results, but I'm unsure how to resolve this. I've tried the following steps without success:

Reinstalled CocoaPods.
Checked and reconfigured build settings or build phase.
Searched for circular dependencies in the project configuration.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. How can I fix this dependency cycle between the XYZ and XYZ_appTests targets? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
